# How to move all commits on top of a specific commit to a new repository in Git?

Tags: git, github

I am currently working on a project and I am using Git for version control.

The project is in a repository with a few other projects. Each of these projects has its own directory.

While all projects except the current one are so small that they can stay in one repository I would like to move the current project to its own Git repository.

My question is now, how can I move all commits at the top of a specific commit to a new repository?

I would be glad if anyone can tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you clarify `how can I move all commits at the top of a specific commit to a new repository?` Does this mean you want a sequential set of commits to be in a new repo? Or does it mean you want all commits in a folder to be in a new repo?

Comment: Github has instructions for [splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a repo with multiple projects like this:

```
projects/
    project1/
    project2/
    project3/
    project4/
```

And you want to turn `project3` into its own repository.

Github has instructions for [splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) which you should be able to use.

1. Make a fresh clone of the old repo (or copy your existing one).
2. Change the [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) to point at the new repo. `git remote set-url origin <new repo url>`. It's important to do this first to avoid accidentally pushing to the old repo.
3. Use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch) to prune everything but the subdirectory you want. `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter project3 master`. All the files that were in `project3/` should now be in the root directory.
4. Push to the new repo. `git push origin master`
5. Once you're satisfied, go to the original clone of the repo and delete `project3/` from the old repo. `git rm project3`

If the push is rejected *don't force it*! Check that `origin` points at the new repository with `git remote -v` and that the new repository is empty.

All the files in `project3` should now be at the top of the directory. The rest of the projects will be gone, safely in the old repo. If you run `git log` you'll still see all the commits that touched those files. It will be as if `project3` was always the only thing in the repository.

Comment: I think all the other answers will also provide a solution for my problem but this one is the most comprehensible and cleanest solution according to my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the project and specify the [`--depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) option. To limit the number of commits you carry and simply delete the other projects to leave the one you want alone.

This isn't exactly the solution you wanted, you simply have to count how many commits you want to carry and set that as the *depth* of the clone.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** This may not be the cleanest solution but it does whatever is asked "move multiple commits from repo A to repo B"

This can be achieved by producing and applying a set of patches.

```
# in repo A
git format patch <sha1 of commit to count from>
# this will produce a bunch of XXXX-<Commit comment>.patch files 
# move those files in newly created repo B
cd <path to repo b>
cp <path to repo a>/*.patch .
git am *.patch # replay patches on top of fresh repo
```

**Update**

Found a better solution with [git-subtree](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/07/extracting-parts-of-git-repository-and-keeping-the-history.html) - this may be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First, we are going to make a variable that is a list of all the commits to the files of a directory, in order from oldest to newest.:

```
folder=<new project>
sha=$(echo $(for x in $(git log --format=oneline --follow $folder| awk '{print $1;}'); do echo $x; done) | awk '{ for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf("%s ",$i); print $1; }')
```

Sorry for the large 1 liner.

You want to make a new repo. You want to be able to cherry-pick the commits from the old project into the new one. We need to set the remote as the old repo, but just take the commits we want to.

```
old=<old project name>
cd ..
mkdir $folder
cd $folder
git init
git remote add $old $(pwd)/$old
```

So now we can get the commits by the hash of commits that we found earlier.

```
for x in $sha; do git cherry-pick $x; done
```

To wrap it all up, we are going to remove our remote link to the old project. Seeing as you tagged this post with github, we will also set a new one to github.

```
git remote rm $old
git remote add origin <url for the new project you created>
```